# PHP 5.4 to 5.3 Conversion

Tags: php

Are their any good resources when you are trying to get a PHP script written in a newer version to work on an older version; Specifically 5.4 to 5.3?

I have even checked out articles about the changes and I cannot seem to figure out what I am doing wrong.

Here is the error I am getting, at this moment:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' in Schedule.php on line 113
```

And the code it is referring to:

```
private static $GAMES_QUERY = array('season' => null, 'gameType' => null);
.....
public function getSeason(){
$test = array_keys(self::$GAMES_QUERY)[0]; //<<<<<<<<<< line:113
return($this->query[$test]);
}
```

Everything I have seen seems to say that 5.3 had self::, array_keys, and the ability to access arrays like that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try...

```
$test = array_keys(self::$GAMES_QUERY);
$test = $test[0];
```

If I'm not mistaken, you can't use the key reference `[0]` in the same declaration in 5.3 like you can in 5.4 and javascript, etc.

Comment: Ah, that does seem to fix it. Is there any syntax that allows that to be done in done in 1 line?

Comment: Thanks, I need to wait a few minutes before I am allowed to accept this.

Comment: like hakre answered you can use list() for a one liner but its another function call vs just a re-declaration... up to you to use either

Answer (score 5):

That syntax was actually added in 5.4: http://docs.php.net/manual/en/migration54.new-features.php

So, you'll need a temporary variable to hold the result of the function, then access the index you want.

Answer (score 1):

In versions lower than PHP 5.4 for the case you have you can make use of the [`list` keyword<sup>*Docs*</sup>](http://www.php.net/function.list):

```
list($test) = array_keys(self::$GAMES_QUERY);
```

That works in PHP 5.4, too. But it does deal better with `NULL` cases than the [new in PHP 5.4 array dereferencing<sup>*Docs*</sup>](http://docs.php.net/migration54.new-features).